# contains a reference to the file "jquery". This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore, symfony6

I'm migrating an old Symfony 3 project to Symfony 6 and I have to migrate a lot of js & css plugins that came with the template (Inspinia) from Assetic to Webpack Encore and Im running into some trouble. When I run "npm run watch" I get these errors:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 16 errors                                                                                            8:30:43 PM

Module build failed: Module not found:
"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/bootstrap.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/footable/footable.all.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/morris/morris.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" contains a reference to the file "pace".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js" contains a reference to the file "codemirror".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/chosen_v1.8.5/chosen.jquery.min.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[1].use[1]!./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css" contains a reference to the file "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[1].use[1]!./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css" contains a reference to the file "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[1].use[1]!./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css" contains a reference to the file "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[1].use[1]!./assets/vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css" contains a reference to the file "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

webpack compiled with 27 errors
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or subdirectory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    
    //.addEntry('jquery', '/assets/vendor/vendor/Inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('bootstrap', '/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    .addEntry('Morris', '/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/morris/morris.js')
    .addEntry('morris2', '/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js')
    .addEntry('inspinia', '/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/inspinia.js')
   // .addEntry('a','https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js')
    .addEntry('b','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js')
    .addEntry('c','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js')
    .addEntry('d','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js')
    .addEntry('e','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/inspinia.js')
    .addEntry('pace','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js')
    .addEntry('g','/assets/vendor/chosen_v1.8.5/chosen.jquery.min.js')
    .addEntry('h','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js')
    .addEntry('i','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js')
    .addEntry('j','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/footable/footable.all.min.js')
    .addEntry('k','/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js')


    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    //.splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    //.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // configure Babel
    // .configureBabel((config) => {
    //     config.plugins.push('@babel/a-babel-plugin');
    // })

    // enables and configure @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Here is my app.js:

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */


// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import './styles/app.css';
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/bootstrap.css' 
import './vendor/Inspinia/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/animate.css' 
import './vendor/chosen_v1.8.5/chosen.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/footable/footable.core.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs3.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/datapicker/datepicker3.css'
//import 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/ladda/ladda-themeless.min.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/dropzone/basic.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/slick/slick.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/slick/slick-theme.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/plugins/c3/c3.min.css'
import './vendor/bootstrap-toggle-master/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css'
//import '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'
import './vendor/Inspinia/css/style.css' 
import './vendor/uncompiled/css/base.scss'



// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';


const $ = require('./vendor/Inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js');
global.$ = global.jQuery = global.jquery = $;

//require('./vendor/Inspinia/js/bootstrap.min.js');
// import 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/ju/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js'
// import '/assets/vendor/Inspinia/js/inspinia.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js'
// import './vendor/chosen_v1.8.5/chosen.jquery.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/footable/footable.all.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/ladda/ladda.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/ladda/ladda.jquery.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/ladda/spin.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/morris/morris.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/slick/slick.min.js' 
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js'   
// import './vendor/bootstrap-toggle-master/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js'
// import '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js'
// import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js'
// import './vendor/uncompiled/js/shared/modal_module.js'
// import './vendor/uncompiled/js/shared/alert_module.js'
// import './vendor/uncompiled/js/shared/flash_message_module.js'
// import './vendor/uncompiled/js/shared/init_module.js'
// import './vendor/dropzone/dropzone.js'
// import './vendor/moment-develop/moment.js'
// import './vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'
// import './vendor/sortable-master/Sortable.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/d3/d3.min.js'
// import './vendor/Inspinia/js/plugins/c3/c3.min.js'
// import './vendor/uncompiled/js/page/shipment_module.js'
```

Am I doing this right? What is the best way to add jquery plugins and custom js to a project like this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I came across same issue updating to node 20

Answer (score 0):

I too came across the similar issue and solution given did not help.

I run the below command

```
npm install --save-dev jquery
```

and then run the command `./node_modules/.bin/encore dev`